# how to add the alt text inside a imgpreview plugin

Tags: jquery

got this map area

```
<area title="hello" alt="hi there" nohref="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/image1.jpg" shape="rect" coords="216,371,418,490" href="#" />
```

and this jquery code

```
$('#first area').imgPreview({
    containerID: 'imgPreviewWithStyles',
    imgCSS: {
        // Limit preview size:
        height: 200
    },
    // When container is shown:
    onShow: function(link){
        $('<span>' + $(link).text() + '</span>').appendTo(this);
    },
    // When container hides: 
    onHide: function(link){
        $('span', this).remove();
    }

});
```

How do I put in a code that displays the alt text of a map area in a appended span created by the imgPreview plugin

I think this is the only section is needed to be changed

```
$('<span>' + $(link).text() + '</span>').appendTo(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

A working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/tariqulazam/3Yckp/

```
// When container is shown:
    onShow: function(link){
        $('<span>' + $(link).attr('alt') + '</span>').appendTo(this);
    }
```